# Javascript, Make time in stopwatch editable

Tags: javascript, html, stopwatch

I am attempting to make my javascript stopwatch run inside some sort of input box, this way if I wanted to change the current calculated time I could just edit the hour, minute, or second. I tried making the time wrapped inside of  html tags but the time would not send from the script into the boxes. Any better ideas of how to make this work???

**Javascript**

```
function _timer(callback)
{
    var time = 0;     //  The default time of the timer
    var status = 0;    //    Status: timer is running or stoped
    var timer_id;    //    This is used by setInterval function

    // this will start the timer
    this.start = function(interval)
    {
        interval = (typeof(interval) !== 'undefined') ? interval : 1000;

        if(status == 0)
        {
            status = 1;
            timer_id = setInterval(function()
            {
                switch(1)
                {
                    case 1:
                    if(time < 86400)
                    {
                        time++;
                        generateTime();
                        if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(time);
                   }
                   break;
                }
            }, interval);
        }
    }

    //  this will stop or pause the timer ex. timer.stop()
    this.stop =  function()
    {
        if(status == 1)
        {
            status = 0;
            clearInterval(timer_id);
        }
    }

    // Reset the timer to zero or reset it to your own custom time
    this.reset =  function(sec)
    {
        sec = (typeof(sec) !== 'undefined') ? sec : 0;
        time = sec;
        generateTime(time);
    }
    // This methode return the current value of the timer and sends it to the database
    this.getTime = function()
    {
        return time;
    }
    // This methode return the status of the timer
    this.getStatus
    {
        return status;
    }

    // This methode will render the time variable to hour:minute:second format
    function generateTime()
    {
        var second = time % 60;
        var minute = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60;
        var hour = Math.floor(time / 3600) % 60;

        second = (second < 10) ? '0'+second : second;
        minute = (minute < 10) ? '0'+minute : minute;
        hour = (hour < 10) ? '0'+hour : hour;

        $('div.timer span.second').html(second);
        $('div.timer span.minute').html(minute);
        $('div.timer span.hour').html(hour);
    }
}

var timer;

$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    timer = new _timer
    (
        function(time)
        {
            if(time == 0)
            {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    );
    timer.reset(0);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="timer">
    <span class="hour"></span>:<span class="minute"></span>:<span class="second"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <button onClick="timer.start(1000)">Start</button>
    <button onClick="timer.stop()">Stop</button>
    <button onClick="timer.reset(0)">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of spans you could use inputs, and instead of `$('div.timer span.second').html(second)` you could have `$('div.timer input.second').value(second)`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak jQuery uses `$().val()` for inputs. Otherwise, Robbie is 100% correct. I believe you would need to have a `focus` eventListener on each of the inputs that pauses the time, and then takes the input and starts the timer again from whatever time you input.

Comment: Okay so I tried what Robbie said and the time did not populate into the input boxes. @LMulvey forgive me but I'm not sure how to write out the evetListeners on the inputs

Comment: @JosiahSequoyah make sure your inputs are type='text' also a listener is just an event handler, for example `${element}.on()` adds a listener to that element, and it listens for what you specify so `${element}.on('click', function())` listens for a click  event and calls a function when it registers one

Comment: @JosiahSequoyah I had to take some liberties with your code but here is a working example of what you're trying to accomplish https://jsfiddle.net/robbiemilejczak/2omdsdkw/6/ let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak hey thanks for putting the time into helping! So your code makes sense but when I start the timer, stop it, enter the new time, and then start it again it goes back to the original time instead of the edited time

Comment: ah of course You'll want to maintain the time variable you can get the value of each unit like this `$('div.timer input.hour').val();` then I would write a function that updates your time variable based on changes to those units so if `hour` is set to `01` then `time = time + 3600`

Comment: @JosiahSequoyah I added some code https://jsfiddle.net/robbiemilejczak/2omdsdkw/7/ so that the second field is editable (see the function verifyTime) hopefully thats enough for you to implement a similar behavior for the other fields. best of luck!

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak you're a genius my man. So I added code https://jsfiddle.net/josiahsequoyah/2omdsdkw/8/ to verifyTime to get the minute updated but when it runs it adds it to the seconds for some reason instead??

Comment: since your `time` variable is the total seconds you need to convert the verifyMin variable to seconds and you'll have to do the same with the hour variable

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak right, so I tried doing minute= Math.floor(time/ 60)%60 to convert minutes to seconds but had no luck

Comment: Yup, you'll wanna do this instead: `(verifyMin - Math.floor(time / 60)) * 60`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak thank you so much for all of your help. You saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final working solution.

**Javascript**

```
function _timer(callback, interval)
{
var time = time || 0;     //  The default time of the timer
var status = 0;    //    Status: timer is running or stoped
var timer_id;    //    This is used by setInterval function
var interval = interval || 1000;
// this will start the timer
this.start = function()
{
            verifyTime();
    if(status == 0)
    {

        status = 1;
        timer_id = setInterval(function()
        {
            switch(1)
            {
                case 1:
                if(time < 86400)
                {
                    time++;
                    generateTime();
                    if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(time);
               }
               break;
            }
        }, interval);
    }
}

//  this will stop or pause the timer ex. timer.stop()
this.stop =  function()
{
    if(status == 1)
    {
        status = 0;
        clearInterval(timer_id);
    }
}

// Reset the timer to zero or reset it to your own custom time
this.reset =  function(sec)
{
    time = 0
    generateTime()
}
// This methode return the current value of the timer and sends it to the database
this.getTime = function()
{
    return time;
}
// This methode return the status of the timer
this.getStatus
{
    return status;
}

// This methode will render the time variable to hour:minute:second format
function generateTime()
{
    console.log(time);
    second = time % 60;
    minute = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60;
    hour = Math.floor(time / 3600) % 60;

    second = (second < 10) ? '0'+second : second;
    minute = (minute < 10) ? '0'+minute : minute;
    hour = (hour < 10) ? '0'+hour : hour;

    $('div.timer input.second').val(second);
    $('div.timer input.minute').val(minute);
    $('div.timer input.hour').val(hour);
}
function verifyTime()
{
    var verifySec =  Number($('div.timer input.second').val());
    second = time % 60;
    verifySec === second ? second = second : time += verifySec - second % 60;
            var verifyMin =  Number($('div.timer input.minute').val());
            minute = (verifyMin - Math.floor(time / 60)) * 60;
            verifyMin === minute ? minute = minute : time += (verifyMin - Math.floor(time / 60)) * 60;
            var verifyHour = Number($('div.timer input.hour').val());
            hour = ((verifyHour - Math.floor(time / 3600)) * 60) * 60;
            verifyHour === hour ? hour = hour : time += ((verifyHour - Math.floor(time / 3600)) * 60) * 60;
}
}

var timer;

$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    timer = new _timer
    (
        function(time)
        {
            if(time == 0)
            {
                timer.stop()
            }
        },
        1000
    );
    $('#start').click(timer.start)
    $('#stop').click(timer.stop)
    $('#reset').click(timer.reset)
    $('.hour').focus(timer.stop)
    $('.hour').focusout(timer.start)
    $('.minute').focus(timer.stop)
    $('.minute').focusout(timer.start)
    $('.second').focus(timer.stop)
    $('.second').focusout(timer.start)
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="timer">
<input type='text' class="hour" />:<input type='text' class="minute" />:<input type='text' class="second" />
</div>
<div>
    <button id='start'>Start</button>
    <button id='stop'>Stop</button>
    <button id='reset'>Reset</button>
</div>
```